# Delete method route error. Possible oversight?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Its a straightforward question. I'm working on AJAX for my app to delete a method. I previously had my code working but now it seems to be broken for some reason. The error I get is that there is a

`No route matches [GET] "/tasks/52"`

I'm confused as to why this error is happening. This is my simple form code:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
<% importance_class = get_importance_class(task.importance) %>
<tr data-id="<%= task.id %>">
  <td class="<%= importance_class%>"><%= task.name %></td>
  <td class="<%= importance_class%>"><%= task.description %></td>
  <td class="<%= importance_class%>"><%= task.start %></td>
  <td class="<%= importance_class%>"><%= task.finish %></td>
  <td class="<%= importance_class%>"><%= task.importance %></td>
  <td class="<%= importance_class%>"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
  <td class="<%= importance_class%>"><%= link_to 'Remove', task_path(task), method: :delete %></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see I have a method: :delete placed and the correct path shown. Is there a possible oversight?

Answer (score 0):

It somehow fixed itself when I restarted rails. Nvm.